# How use inner join using 2 variable field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables ABC and XYZ I want to inner join the with name field.

**ABC  table**

```
     Name     Address     Phone
   Nirdosh    Kth         96749343
   Hari       pokhara     98493434
```

**XYZ table**

```
    Name      Address   Phone
   Shrestha    Daldale  96749343
    Hari       pokhara     98493434
```

I use INNER JOIN

```
select actual.*,more.* 
from ABC actual 
INNER JOIN Xyz more 
ON like %'actual.Name'% = like %'more.Name'%
```

Comment: `ON actual.Name = more.Name`?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: None of the names in the two tables are the same. What result do you expect?

Comment: The title says "using 2 variable field"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying more.Name is *more or like* actual.Name, but need not be *exactly* the same as actual.Name?

```
select actual.*, more.*
from ABC actual 
inner join XYZ more on more.Name like concat('%', trim(actual.Name), '%')
```